# use existing database instead of django database

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database, web-applications

i want to connect my existing database of sql server with django but the problem is django has its model which create its own database but i dont want to create database using django i just want to use mine to retrieve data.
the one solution i saw was to use inspectdb but hte problem with inspectdb is that it does not pick wring keys and constraints sometime plus have to set many thing manually but in my project my database is user defined user will connect its database so i dont actually know that how many and what table user's database have do i just want to connect that database with django and use the value of it.
my existing database is sqlserver.
any technique to use my existing database without using django database and retrive data from existing database.
thankyou.

Comment: one more important this i have to automate this because i dont really know the quantity and names of table

Answer (score 0):

As you mentionned, you should use : inspectdb to create your models as stated in the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/)

Setting the [managed option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#managed) to False in the Meta class of model, you can instruct Django to not make any migrations or database schema modification, but you need to tweak the model yourself to ensure every kind of mapping is as you intendend, and obviousl ensure coherence between your DB schema and models.

Comment: but i cannot able to tweak model by my self because i dont know how many table the user's database will have?

Comment: I don't understand your statement. What do you mean by "I don't know how many table the user's db will have" and why does it matter ? When you are using an ORM from an existing db, you must know how to map your models to your DB.

Comment: i am developing a project in which user will connect its datasource then create charts on it so i dont know the quantity of tables of user database or the names of table so how can i set the table in django model

Comment: You will need to dynamically write your models I guess, don't know if django provide an API for its inspector so you can plug in your code .